# Django admin cannot add dynamically fields to form

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to set form fields dynamically and access it in `admin.py` in `get_forms` method, but unfortunately, dynamic data is not there. It seems like forms `__init__` is being called after the `get_form` itself. Which would appropriate method in Django admin to retrieve already updated form fields?

Here is simple example

forms.py

```
class MyForm(admin.ModelForm):

   title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextArea)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     self.fields.update({
       'some_field': forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextArea)
     })
```

admin.py

```
class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

   def get_form(self, request, **kwargs):
      form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
      print(form.base_fields)
      return form
```